# Quantum numbers in spherical symmetric potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Can we proof the relation that the  principal quantum number $n$ and azimuthal quantum number $l$ have the relation $l=0,1,...n-1$  in any spherical symmetric potential $V(r)$ or this just apply to Coulomb  potential?

I would appreciate reference to books or articles

Answer (score 1):

This relationship does not hold for all spherically-symmetric potentials. For example, for the [3D harmonic oscillator](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator#Example:_3D_isotropic_harmonic_oscillator) the relationship between $n$ and $l$ is

$$l=0,2,4,...,n$$

for even $n$ and

$$l=1,3,5,...,n$$

for odd $n$.

Comment: So why in multi electrons atoms we have this relation,since in multi electron atoms we approximate the potential to be spherically-symmetric potentials?

Comment: @amiltonmoreira But we do more than this. To first approximation (the orbital approximation) we consider each electron to have hydrogen-like orbitals created from an effective nuclear charge $Z_{eff}$ created from the nuclear charge and shielding of inner electrons. See https://www.chemicool.com/definition/orbital-approximation.html

Answer (score 0):

The radial $P(r,\nu,l)$ part of the wave function in a central potential obey a one dimensional Schrodinger equation an so it is characterized by the number of nodes $\nu$, and since the equation contains $l$ it is also characterized by the quantum number $l$.
Now we define 
$n=l+\nu+1$

So instead of characterizing the radial part by $l$ and $\nu$  we characterize it by $l$ and $n$ ,that is, the radial part of the wave function is of the form  $P(r,n,l)$.
Now since the number of nodes $\nu$ and angular number $l$ are positive integer we should
have $l=0,1,...n-1$