# Quantum numbers $n$ and $\ell$ relation in many electrons atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, approximations, orbitals

Solving the Schrodinger equation for hydrogen atom we arrive to the conclusion that quantum numbers $n$ and $\ell$ have the relation $$\ell=0,1,...,n-1.$$

Now,since we can not solve the Schrodinger equation for many electrons atoms we can approximate the potential $V(r_i)$ to be central than Hamiltonian becomes
$$ \hat H= \sum_i \left( -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \nabla_i^2 +V(r_i) \right).$$

So for each electron we have the following equation 
$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \nabla_i^2\psi_i +V(r_i)\psi_i=E\psi_i.$$

And solution is of the form

$$\psi_i=R_i^{n,\ell}(r)Y^m_{\ell}(\theta, \phi).$$

My question is why quantum numbers $n$ and $\ell$ have the relation
$$\ell=0,1,...,n-1.$$

Is this an assumption or can we proof it?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/238180/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Their not the same question since what i am just  concerned  about the relation between $\ell$  and $n$ with the assumption that the potential is central

Comment: Do you understand why $\ell$ cannot be larger than $n-1$ for the hydrogen atom?

Comment: yes,solving radial part and imposing some conditions we arrive to the relation

Comment: The OP already asked the same question https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/450330/  for which there is a perfectly valid answer: the range $0 \le \ell \le n-1$ is specific to the Coulomb potential.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Yes, however there does seem to be an issue which needs clarification: John Rennie's answer in Qmechanics link states the requirement of "any smooth monotonic central potential" but in your link we have the counter example of the "3D harmonic oscillator". Are we saying the harmonic oscillator potential is not smooth monotonic?

Comment: @BruceGreetham not sure I understand your comment.  The rangle of $\ell$ depends on the specific potential, and we typically assume it’s smooth.  If you solve for the  various central potentials you will get different ranges, an in many cases there no relation between $\ell$ and $n$.  $n$ just labels the order of appearance of an $\ell$ value.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I accept you are right. But that seems to imply John Rennie's answer (which got 27 votes) is wrong. This seems to morally justify the OPs confusion - you should be able to ask the same question again if existing SE answers contradict.

Comment: Amilton, if you understand why $\ell$ cannot be larger than $n-1$ for hydrogen, then how do you not see why it arises here? Also if you want a specific user to see your comment do "@username" in your comment

Comment: Because in the hydrogen atom the potential is done explicitly  so we can solve it and we can impose certain condition to radial function. But in the central approximation it is only said that the potential is central nothing more so how can we see it ?  @username

Comment: @amiltonmoreira I think the solution you give assumes a $1/r^2$ potential energy function. Can you reference what you are looking at?

Comment: Just trying to proof the multi electron configuration.This can be done using the Pauli exclusion principle and this can be done only if $0 \le \ell \le n-1$. For example if  had $\ell=n$, than the state $1p$ would be possible. To the justification for this relation $0 \le \ell \le n-1$ in atomic physics books is that the potential is central  but they do not specify the potential.